# telegram bot login checking authorization not equal hash

Tags: node.js, telegram, telegram-bot, telegraf

I try to use telegram bot connect website, when I open the website, I get the query and hash when I validate throw node.js and not equal

```
const key = crypto.createHash('sha256').update(my_bot_token).digest()
const validateHash = crypto.createHmac('sha256', key).update('auth_date=1646xxx\nfirst_name=namexxx\nid=1231xxxx\nAusername=alexLxxx').digest('hex')
console.log(hash === validateHash) false
```

I don't know where I am going wrong I try to use the npm package [telegram-checking-authorization](https://github.com/lolitaframework/telegram-checking-authorization), but the same error

Answer (score 1):

It happened to me as well, I described it in [My question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74762656/telegram-check-authorization-hash-mismatch). You might copy the response from this API: `https://oauth.telegram.org/auth/get?bot_id=xxx` sometimes the response works with the function, sometimes it doesn't, and honestly, I don't understand why. Try to print `user` to console and check if the two hashes match!

**What I have done is as follow:**

I changed my bot's domain to `https://www.w3schools.com/` and go to w3school online editor `https://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_string_indexof` for example, print `user` object to console (replace the javascript in the online editor with code bellow and then replace YOUR-BOT-NAME in the code with the name of your bot):

```
<script async src="https://telegram.org/js/telegram-widget.js?21" data-telegram-login="YOUR-BOT-NAME" data-size="large" data-onauth="onTelegramAuth(user)" data-request-access="write"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  function onTelegramAuth(user) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(user, null, 2));
  }
</script>
```

2. press f12, go to console tab and then login with widget. Check the data printed on the console with your function.

Comment: I tend to have issues with my bot on other browsers apart  from firefox I am no getting  request from telegram

Answer (score 0):

You should add all field data you receive from the request callback but remove the `hash` field.
Ex:

```
`auth_date=1665991955
first_name=xxxxx
id=xxxxxx
last_name=xxxxx
photo_url=xxxxxxx
username=xxxxx`
```

I try and succeed.