# Telegram: check authorization hash mismatch

Tags: javascript, node.js, authorization, telegram

I'm trying to use javascript to implement this [Telegram PHP example](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/6516521b1fb3b464534fbc30ea3573c2), but the hashes don't match. I ran the example's php code; it also failed, and the hash returned by the example and mine are identical. I'm wondering if it has anything to do with my bot settings (I set my domain to 127.0.0.1 and try another https domain - still failed). I'm completely stuck and have no idea how to make it work.

My code is as follows:

```
'use strict';

const sha256 = require('crypto-js/sha256');
const hmacSHA256 = require('crypto-js/hmac-sha256');
const Hex = require('crypto-js/enc-hex');

const { ValidationError } = require('objection');

const data = {
id: 5528016998,
first_name: 'Lê Văn',
last_name: 'Hùng',
username: 'HungLV46',
photo_url: 'https://t.me/i/userpic/320/gy_L5Q2zLLZyUrtCw0Fh9D0oy0CuabiM2A0-68FY27Inz94yP7ypxCrAF7G7_asy.jpg',
auth_date: 1670774122,
hash: '893e4bd66128d8696d63aa285b0aff6e8b970cbe9c9e43dacfa9e2da7420c16c'
};

function verifyAuthorization(params) {
if ((new Date() - new Date(params.auth_date * 1000)) > 86400000) { // milisecond
    throw new ValidationError('Authorization data is outdated');
}

const verificationParams = { ...params };
delete verificationParams.hash;

const message = Object.keys(verificationParams)
    .map(key => `${key}=${verificationParams[key]}`)
    .sort().join('\n');
const secretKey = sha256('xxxx'); // replace with the token of my bot
const hash = Hex.stringify(hmacSHA256(message, secretKey));

if (hash !== params.hash) {
    throw new ValidationError('Authorization data is not from telegram!');
}
}

verifyAuthorization(data);
```

[similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71299151/telegram-bot-login-checking-authorization-not-equal-hash)

**Edit:**

After experimenting with the login widget for some time, I tried to print return value to the developer console of Chrome (pressing f12, console tab), and then run my code again. The 2 hashes **awardly match**!.

I initially got the user info and hash from the response of this API, `POST https://oauth.telegram.org/auth/get?bot_id=xxx` in network-tab, and it turned out the response of API in network-tab was different from the response printed in console-tab.

I tried some more time, and the response of the API suddenly worked well with my function. Now I am just curious about why?